# Firebase Functions deploying Not Working, Rejected with [ Server Error. Client network socket disconnected ]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my firebase functions but it's giving me an error.

```
⚠  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

[image]

**Firebase Debug Log**

```
[warn] ⚠  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
[debug] [2020-04-04T17:59:21.405Z] Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1361:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Comment: If you're having problems deploying with the Firebase CLI, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: There is the same problem for uploading the file:

network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established',
>    type: 'system',
>    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
>    code: 'ECONNRESET'
>  }

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I was communicated with firebase support team. They told it's my internet issues. Then after using a VPN may problem was solved. You can try using VPN or change you network.

Answer (score 0):

This problem often happens due to slow internet connection. Please check your Internet connection.

Comment: I have been trying lots of time but still, give me the same error. I think my net speed is ok. There is no problem with other sites.